# Using concurrent classes to process files in a directory in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I am trying to figure out how to use the types from the `java.util.concurrent` package to parallelize processing of all the files in a directory.

I am familiar with the multiprocessing package in Python, which is very simple to use, so ideally I am looking for something similar:

```
public interface FictionalFunctor<T>{
  void handle(T arg);
}

public class FictionalThreadPool {
  public FictionalThreadPool(int threadCount){
    ...
  }
  public <T> FictionalThreadPoolMapResult<T> map(FictionalFunctor<T> functor, List<T> args){
    // Executes the given functor on each and every arg from args in parallel. Returns, when
    // all the parallel branches return.
    // FictionalThreadPoolMapResult allows to abort the whole mapping process, at the least.
  }
}

dir = getDirectoryToProcess();
pool = new FictionalThreadPool(10);   // 10 threads in the pool
pool.map(new FictionalFunctor<File>(){ 
  @Override
  public void handle(File file){
    // process the file
  }
}, dir.listFiles());
```

I have a feeling that the types in `java.util.concurrent` allow me to do something similar, but I have absolutely no idea where to start.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

Following the advices given in the answers, I have written something like this:

```
public void processAllFiles() throws IOException {
  ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
  BlockingQueue<Runnable> tasks = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5); // Figured we can keep the contents of 6 files simultaneously.
  exec.submit(new MyCoordinator(exec, tasks));
  for (File file : dir.listFiles(getMyFilter()) {
    try {
      tasks.add(new MyTask(file));
    } catch (IOException exc) {
      System.err.println(String.format("Failed to read %s - %s", file.getName(), exc.getMessage()));
    }
  }
}

public class MyTask implements Runnable {
  private final byte[] m_buffer;
  private final String m_name;

  public MyTask(File file) throws IOException {
    m_name = file.getName();
    m_buffer = Files.toByteArray(file);
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Process the file contents
  }
}

private class MyCoordinator implements Runnable {
  private final ExecutorService m_exec;
  private final BlockingQueue<Runnable> m_tasks;

  public MyCoordinator(ExecutorService exec, BlockingQueue<Runnable> tasks) {
    m_exec = exec;
    m_tasks = tasks;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    while (true) {
      Runnable task = m_tasks.remove();
      m_exec.submit(task);
    }
  }
}
```

How I **thought** the code works is:

1. The files are read one after another.
2. A file contents are saved in a dedicated `MyTask` instance.
3. A blocking queue with the capacity of 5 to hold the tasks. I count on the ability of the server to keep the contents of at most 6 files at one time - 5 in the queue and another fully initialized task waiting to enter the queue.
4. A special `MyCoordinator` task fetches the file tasks from the queue and dispatches them to the same pool.

OK, so there is a bug - more than 6 tasks can be created. Some will be submitted, even though all the pool threads are busy. I've planned to solve it later.

The problem is that it does not work at all. The `MyCoordinator` thread blocks on the first remove - this is fine. But it never unblocks, even though new tasks were placed in the queue. Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread pool you are looking for is the [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) class. You can create a fixed-size thread pool using `newFixedThreadPool`. This allows you to easily implement a producer-consumer pattern, with the pool encapsulating all the queue and worker functionality for you:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

You can then submit tasks in the form of objects whose type implements `Runnable` (or `Callable` if you want to also get a result):

```
class ThreadTask implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
       // task code
    }
}

...

exec.submit(new ThreadTask());
// alternatively, using an anonymous type
exec.submit(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              // task code
           }
      });
```

**A big word of advice** on processing multiple files in parallel: if you have a single mechanical disk holding the files it's wise to use a single thread to read them one-by-one and submit each file to a thread pool task as above, for processing. Do not do the actual reading in parallel as it will degrade performance.

Comment: Though the **big word of advice** is absolutely true, it could eat a lot of memory to read all of them first.  And maybe the disk cache is doing a good job to maintain performance.  But the bottom line is that sometimes processing files from disk in parallel is not a time saver, and processing in serial is faster or nearly as fast, and much simpler.

Comment: @Tudor Can you explain why did u put that "big word of advice" ? In other words why would actual reading in parallel degrade performance ?

Comment: @Geek: With a single mechanical disk the head of the disk needs to seek the next reading location for each read request. This is a costly operation and since multiple threads issue read commands it means the head gets bounced around as each thread gets its turn to run. This will drastically reduce performance compared to the case where a single thread is doing the reading.

Comment: @Tudor - I have tried to implement the scheme, where I, on one hand, read all the files in a single thread, but on the other hand, process them in parallel. Something is wrong in my understanding of the details - see the edit of the question.

Comment: @mark: Your implementation is too complicated imo. You do not need to use a queue explicitly to hold the tasks because the thread pool already encapsulates a queue. All you have to do is create a task class that encapsulates the contents of an already read file (like a string array) and keep creating and submitting such tasks whenever you finish reading a file.

Comment: @Tudor - How do you suggest to limit the number of files, which contents are kept in memory? I mean, I cannot allow having 100 tasks awaiting in the queue, since every task contains the whole contents of some file. I need the thread feeding the queue to block when the queue hits the limit, say 5 tasks.

Comment: @mark: Ah, I see what you mean. You could try to use a simple `wait/notify`. So when a task is submitted a counter is incremented and when it hits 5 the producer calls `wait`. Then at the end of each task the counter is decremented and `notify` is called to wake up the producer.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler solution than using ExecuterService is to implement your own producer-consumer scheme. Have a thread that create tasks and submits to a LinkedBlockingQueue or ArrayBlockingQueue and have worker threads that check this queue to retrieve the tasks and do them. You may need a special kind of tasks name ExitTask that forces the workers to exit. So at the end of the jobs if you have n workers you need to add n ExitTasks into the queue.

Comment: I really don't see how this is easier than `ExecutorService`, which already encapsulates both the queue and the workers polling the queue for work. Basically all you have to do is submit work.

Comment: It is not necessarily easier but simpler in the sense of concept as it only relies on the producer-consumer concept.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, what @Tudor said, use an ExecutorService, but I wanted to expand on his code and I always feel strange editing other people's posts.  Here's a sksleton of what you would submit to the ExecutorService:

```
public class MyFileTask implements Runnable {
   final File fileToProcess;

   public MyFileTask(File file) {
      fileToProcess = file;
   }

   public void run() {
      // your code goes here, e.g.
      handle(fileToProcess);
      // if you prefer, implement Callable instead
   }
}
```

See also [my blog post here for some more details if you get stuck](http://flyingspaniel.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-parallelize-your-algorithm-with.html)

Since processing Files often leads to IOExceptions, I'd prefer a Callable (which can throw a checked Exception) to a Runnable, but YMMV.